# Android CustomAttribute in MotionLayout to change Text in TextView

Tags: android, android-custom-attributes, android-motionlayout

**Anyone can help me with the correct way to change `TextView`'s text in `MotionLayout`... this is what I doing.**

I'm testing the `MotionLayout` on a Simple App...
I reach the part on the [Motion tutorials](https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-ii-a31acc084f59) about `CustomAttributes`

With them you can change the `BackgroundColor` of a `View`, also the `textColor` using `customColorValue`

In this case you can see it works very well changing this values in the start and end scene:

```
        <CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="backgroundColor"
            motion:customColorValue="#004A6D" />

        <CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="textColor"
            motion:customColorValue="#000000" />
```

[image]

Also I note that there is a `customStringValue` so I think I can change the `TextView` text to "BEFORE" -> "AFTER". But when I try to set this with `CustomAttribute` the app crash.

In the start scene:

```
<CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="Text"
            motion:customStringValue="BEFORE" />
```

And in the final scene:

```
        <CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="Text"
            motion:customStringValue="AFTER" />
```

Outside MotionScene the `textView` text is **TEST**:

- When I set the `CustomAttribute` only for the end scene... the text change from initial value **TEST** to the end **AFTER** value... so it partially works but never return to the initial state.
- This happend also when there is not initial text setted on the `TextView`. It works partially.

[image]

**So... anyone can help me with the correct way to change `TextView`'s text in `MotionLayout`.**

Comment: Oscar, did you find any solution for this? I am having the same issue :(

Comment: If not, did you report this issue to Google?

Answer (score 5):

Easy way of doing this is

```
 <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="textColor"
            app:customColorValue="#1D1D1D" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

```
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="textColor"
            app:customColorValue="#FFFFFF" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

Change motion to app

Comment: With `constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6` changing from `motion` to `app`  actually works. I don't even... ‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

you can do it programmatically using a TransitionListener like this:

```
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {
        // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
    }

    override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
    }

    override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {
        textView.text = if(p3==0f) "before" else "after"
    }

    override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {

    }
})
```

Comment: This worked for me. I think we need to use this workaround for now until Google releases  bug fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

I test and like this

[image]

```
//constraintSetStart
<ConstraintSet...>
<Constraint
  android:id="@+id/button">
    <CustomAttribute
       motion:attributeName="Text"
       motion:customStringValue="CLOSE"/>
</Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>

//constraintSetEnd
<ConstrainSet..>
<Constraint
   android:id="@+id/button">
     <CustomAttribute
       motion:attributeName="Text"
       motion:customStringValue="OPEN"/>
 </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```